# Strange error on rendering an image in an email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, email, ruby-on-rails-4, assets

I am runnning Ruby on Rails 4.1 in production mode and I send a successful email from my web application to my GMail account. This email contains an image (the app logo) but this image is not displayed in the message body.

Logging the image request on the server side I get the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/my_app_logo.png")
```

Inspecting the email source code I get:

```
<img class="CToWUd" alt="MyAppName" src="https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/J8xdV03MSjJGOJh6F8T5ntqhjC2YJAiShAWJshvcOLn9THWAC5hKwp4DCLc6csuoojWlaKzPXjt-6zBAkZZvzpYMH=s0-d-e1-ft#http://www.my_app_name.com/assets/my_app_logo.png">
```

What is the problem? How can I solve it?

---

In my partial template I have:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("#{root_url}assets/my_app_logo.png", :alt => MyAppName), root_url.to_s) %>
```

---

**Update** after @kasperite's comment

> Can you post what's in application.css? also is it application.css
>   under assets/stylesheets?

Yes, my `application.css.scss` file is `assets/stylesheets`:

```
// ...
.my_app_logo { background-image: image-url("my_app_logo.png"); display: inline-block; }
// ...
```

However the `application.css.scss` is *not* used for rendering the email. I use the code as stated in the above partial template.

Comment: do you have config.serve_static_assets set to false in production environment?

Comment: Yes, I have `config.serve_static_assets = false` in production environment.

Comment: is `assets` folder under public or app?I thought you are not supposed to access `app/assets` in production?

Comment: @kasperite - The logo image is in the `app\assets` directory. Note: I am using Capistrato to deploy so I have a `shared` directory.

Comment: I read [How to Use the Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline): *Assets can still be placed in the public hierarchy. Any assets under public will be served as static files by the application or web server. You should use app/assets for files that must undergo some pre-processing before they are served. In production, Rails precompiles these files to public/assets by default. The precompiled copies are then served as static assets by the web server. The files in app/assets are never served directly in production.* Maybe it can help...

Comment: hmm, what if you put the image under `public/images`, will it work?You can put it under `app/assets/images` then it should bundle up into `public/images` for you after deployment

Comment: @kasperite - In development mode I get the `Sprockets::FileNotFound` (raised from the `application.css` file) error since I moved the image file. Should I duplicate it?

Comment: can you post what's in `application.css`?also is it application.css under `assets/stylesheets`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that after your assets get compiled for Production, my_app_logo.png does not technically exist anymore.  It is actually renamed by appending a fingerprint onto the asset, so the actual asset is my_app_logo-SOME_FINGERPRINT_STRING.png.

The crux of the issue is you are attempting to do an absolute path to the image in your `image_tag` helper.  Try doing this instead:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag("my_app_logo.png", :alt => MyAppName), root_url.to_s) %>
```

This should generate the proper link to the renamed image.